# How can I schedule a PAGE to go live at a future date/time?

Tags: posts, pages, publish

I have no problem scheduling posts to go live at a future date/time, but last year, when I launched my site, it crashed when I tried scheduling a static page to go live (specifically, I believe it unpublished the page). It's a subpage, not the homepage.

Does anyone know how to schedule a static page to go live just like a post? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

To schedule a WordPress page for future date or time, you just need to adjust the date and the time shown on the screenshot below. You have to also be careful not to schedule on a passed date that could be the problem. You can also refresh the page and try once again.

[image: Scheduling WordPress Page]

If the error persist it possibly has to do with your wp-cron set up. To understand how wp cron works here is a resourceful article https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to schedule a page to go live. https://en.support.wordpress.com/pages/schedule-a-page/

It doesn't make sense that your site crashed when scheduling a page to go live. I don't think scheduling had anything to do with your site crashing.

Scheduling does work, make sure you keep your WordPress Core, your plugins and themes up-to-date and all should be good.